# Comparing a vector of averages to a null one

Tags: multiple-comparisons, multivariate-analysis

Measurement outcome is a continuous number measured in $p$ locations.
This yields a vector $X_1$ to $X_p$ per subject. These vectors are obtained on $N$ subjects.
In addition these $N$ subjects come from $k$ groups.

What method should I use to compare the average vector across the entire study population to an hypothesized null?

And how to compare between the $k$ groups the per group average vector overall and for individual $X_i$ locations?

Comment: Are you asking for multivariate hypothesis tests? For your first question, if you're looking for a multivariate equivalent to a t-test, you might consider Hotelling's T-Squared. For the second question, are you trying to compare k groups? Is MANOVA appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

It may not make sense to take an unweighted average of all $N$ observations if the subjects are divided among $k$ subpopulations [=groups] - unless the sample sizes in the groups are proportional to the sizes of the subpopulations. Otherwise, what characteristic[s] of interest would an unweighted average estimate?

Your sample design seems to be that of a 1-way MANOVA - so you could finesse the issue of unequal treatment [=group] means by including [vector] group-effect terms in a MANOVA model. Then the logical thing is to test first for no group differences [with the appropriate MANOVA procedure] - and if it appears there are none - the $N$ observations can then be averaged and tested using Hotelling's-$T^2$.

Comment: @mbq thanks for having the patience to correct my lazy typing.

Comment: and what if the distribution is not multivariate normal? Also, the vector might have 0 in certain locations (not necessarily the same for all subjects e.g. X1=0, and X7=0 for one subject and X3=0 for another etc.). Is it still ok to use MANOVA?